# How do I get export to CSV JS/JQ to also open in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that we have built some reporting capabilities into, and would like to have the JS/JQ open the report into a new tab.

```
   ;(function($) {

    $.Oscampus.statistics.setPagination('student');

    $('#student-list').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $.Oscampus.statistics.load('students');
    });

    $(".hasTooltip").tooltip({"html": true, "container": "body"})


})(jQuery);
```

========================

```
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
var csv = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
        row.push('"' + cols[j].innerText.replace('"', '\\"') + '"');

    csv.push(row.join(",")); 

}

// Download CSV file
downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}
```

===================

```
    var csvFile;
var downloadLink;

// CSV file
csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

// Download link
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

// File name
downloadLink.download = filename;

// Create a link to the file
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

// Hide download link
downloadLink.style.display = "none";

// Add the link to DOM
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

// Click download link
downloadLink.click();
}
```

The above code works great, but determining where to include the var for _blank is proving difficult for this humble dev. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

you want to open the report into a new tab to download or show?
if you want to download,try this:

```
exportTableToCSV('filename.csv');

function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [],
            cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
            row.push('"' + cols[j].innerText.replace('"', '\\"') + '"');

        csv.push(row.join(","));

    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {

    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;
    var targetWind = window.open();

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });

    // Download link
    downloadLink = targetWind.document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = targetWind.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    targetWind.document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The initial code that I posted indicates three parts: The user clicks a button that takes them to a page where the statistics are displayed in a table (sections one and two, jQuery and JS, respectively), and the third section creates a CSV out of that table for download. When the initial table export occurs (first two sections), how do I get the export to open in a new tab?

Comment: did you mean that you want to open in a new tab and show the table data and download the table data by clicking a button ?see this demo:https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/es6f755y/3/

Comment: Almost, what we would like is to have the initial generation of the table be what opens in a new tab, with the download option displaying with the table data in that new tab. I think the jQuery at the top is where we need to have the code snippet. There is a button with id="student-list" in the HTML, and the jQuery has  --$('#student-list').on('click', function(evt) {--    in it, which I think is where we want to have the window.open function.

Answer (score 1):

```
downloadLink.target = '_blank';
```

Believe this should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! Placed where, exactly?

Comment: Ah sorry, in your downloadCSV function, anywhere after 

    // Download link
    downloadLink = targetWind.document.createElement("a");

and before 

    // Add the link to DOM
    targetWind.document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately, I think it is needed earlier in the code, which would change downloadLink to csv or rows or something else, as it would be included in the earlier scripts.

Comment: may not work simply because new window opening requires user event in most browsers dues to all the abuse over the years